# which parameters can i pass in bundle for facebook WebDialog (Facebook Android SDK 3.5)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am learning Facebook Android SDK, and i am stucked here. I am creating Feed Dialog by following [Official guidlines from developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/feed-dialog/)

I want to know that which keys we can specify in the `Bundle` that we are passing in the `WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder` method (as shown below in the code). As we can see that here we are passing `"name", "caption", "description", "link", "picture"` (i want to know the other options)

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");


WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
```

I could not find any useful resource on it. I have also looked at [WebDialog SDK Reference.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/WebDialog/)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any parameter specified in the feed dialog documentation (your first link) can be put in the params bundle.

Comment: @MingLi i want to know what other parameters can be specified than those defined here. I have seen on a SO discussion that we can also specify `to` with the bundle. (although, now facebook does not support this parameter.)

Comment: I misread your first link, here's the full docs on the feed dialog, it includes a list of parameters you can pass in. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

app_id:  Your app's unique identifier. Required.

redirect_uri: The URL to redirect to after a person clicks a button on the dialog. Not required for Android SDK usage.

display: Determines how the dialog is rendered. Not required for Android SDK usage.

from:  The ID or username of the person posting the message. If this is unspecified, it defaults to the current person. If specified, it must be the ID of the person or of a page that the person administers.

to: The ID or username of the profile that this story will be published to. If this is unspecified, it defaults to the value of from.

link: The link attached to this post

picture: The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px. See our documentation on maximizing distribution for media content for more information on sizes.

source: The URL of a media file (either SWF or MP3) attached to this post. If both source and picture are specified, only source is used.

name:  The name of the link attachment.

caption: The caption of the link (appears beneath the link name). If not specified, this field is automatically populated with the URL of the link.

description: The description of the link (appears beneath the link caption). If not specified, this field is automatically populated by information scraped from the link, typically the title of the page.

properties: A JSON object of key/value pairs which will appear in the stream attachment beneath the description, with each property on its own line. Keys must be strings, and values can be either strings or JSON objects with the keys text and href.

actions: A JSON array containing a single object describing the action link which will appear next to the 'Comment' and 'Like' link under posts. The contained object must have the keys name and link.

ref: A string (must be less than 50 characters and contain only alphanumeric or +/=-.:_ characters) reference for the category of feed post. This category is used in Facebook Insights to help you measure the performance of different types of post

Comment: regarding these properties:
`to` - I found from [February 6, 2013](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/) facebook changes that posting on friend's wall by Graph API isn't available anymore. Thus the `to` property won't work. //
`source` - What is the permission to use here? because it doesn't work nor with `publish_action` either `publish_stream`. I found new [`attachment` and `media`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments) properties which should be used for publishing MP3 //
`message` - isn't mentioned, but still working

Comment: This answer only applies to the Feed Dialog, not to the graph API's me/feed endpoint. The Feed Dialog (since it's a web dialog), still allows posting to a friend's timeline.

Comment: Try setting it to be the empty string.